# Android gradle unit test can't find library

Tags: android, gradle

I enjoyed using gradle right up until I started writing unit tests.  The problem I am currently experiencing is that my gradle build cannot find ActionBarPullToRefresh layout when running unit tests.  My gradle build file is as follows

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

sourceSets {
    unitTest {
        java.srcDir file('src/main/java/com/smartsocialmedia/tests')
        resources.srcDir file('src/main/res/com/smartsocialmedia/tests')
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java/com/smartsocialmedia']
    }
}

configurations {
    unitTestCompile.extendsFrom runtime
    unitTestRuntime.extendsFrom unitTestCompile
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.0'

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 7
    versionName "1.0.5"
    testPackageName "com.smartsocialmedia.tests"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    //testHandlingProfiling true
    testFunctionalTest true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.1.2@jar'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:+'
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.1-with-sources.jar')

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    unitTestCompile files("$project.buildDir/classes/release")
    unitTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
    unitTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.1.+'
    unitTestCompile 'com.google.android:android:4.0.1.2'
    unitTestCompile 'com.google.android:android-test:4.1.1.4'
    unitTestCompile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.1-with-sources.jar')
    unitTestCompile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.1.2@jar'
    unitTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    unitTestCompile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:+'

}

task unitTest(type:Test, dependsOn: assemble) {
    testClassesDir = project.sourceSets.unitTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = project.sourceSets.unitTest.runtimeClasspath
}
check.dependsOn unitTest
```

Basically what I want to do is have this https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh library included in my unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to test a class from 'module-a' that had imports from another module `module-b`.  I couldn't run the test in 'module-a' because it references imports only available to `module-b` so I moved the class to `module-b`.

To reference `module-a` from `module-b` I did this in the `build.gradle` of `module-b`

```
sourceSets {
    test.java.srcDirs = [
            "${rootProject.getRootDir()}/path/to/module-a",
            "${rootProject.getRootDir()}/path/to/module-b"

    ]
}
```

After that I had an error saying I should check the classpath and the .jar library `module-b` depends on was not compiling.

So in the build.gradle of `module-b`, under `dependencies{..}`

```
api fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Notice the `api`, it was `implementation` and it did not work.

Hope this helps someone!